# Accessing the child of a child in a JSON with Handlebars.js

Tags: json, handlebars.js

I'm having no trouble accessing the initial child of the parent object in a json, however, I cannot seem to figure out what the format for accessing the child of a child is. I'm currently using dot notation as described in the handlebars.js documentation.

My html with handlebars.js implemented (the 'Fees' aren't showing correctly, they show up as [object Object]):

```
    {{#options}}
    {{#company_base}}
    <div>
        <h1>{{name_full}}</h1><b>AM Best Rating</b>: {{ambest_rating}}

        <p><b>Type</b>: {{business_type}}</p>

        <p><b>Fees</b>:
            <ol>

                <li><b>Type</b>: {{../..options.fees.type}}</li>
                <li><b>Name</b>: {{../..options.fees.name}}</li>

            </ol>
        </p>
    </div>
    {{/company_base}}
    {{/options}}
```

My mock JSON:

```
{
 "options": [{
     "company_base": {
         "business_type": "Life, Accident, and Health",
         "established_year": 1998,
         "med_supp_state_market_data": [{
             "market_share": 0.63490064689900005,
             "state": "AK",
             "lives": 8041,
             "premiums": 14714825,
             "claims": 11649263
         }, {
             "market_share": 0.34445359987700003,
             "state": "WY",
             "lives": 14916,
             "premiums": 30178554,
             "claims": 24281001
         }],
         "underwriting_data": [],
         "med_supp_national_market_data": {
             "market_share": 0.315510079562,
             "state": null,
             "lives": 3723184,
             "premiums": 8276072271,
             "claims": 6436017316
         },
         "customer_complaint_ratio": 0.0013368044250809999,
         "ambest_outlook": "Stable",
         "name_full": "Major Health Partners of the Wind",
         "ambest_rating": "A",
         "parent_company": "aghzfmNzZ2sdfZWRfc3VwcA",
         "last_modified": "2017-01-16T12:28:17.591830",
         "customer_satisfaction_ratio": 0.83666666666699996,
         "default_resources": {
             "final-expense-life": {
                 "e_app_link": ""
             },
             "medicare-advantage": {
                 "e_app_link": ""
             },
             "medicare-supplement": {
                 "e_app_link": "sdf"
             },
             "hospital-indemnity": {
                 "e_app_link": ""
             },
             "dental": {
                 "e_app_link": ""
             }
         },
         "key": "assdfsdfVwcA",
         "parent_company_base": {
             "established_year": 1998,
             "code": "707",
             "name": "Space Insurance",
             "key": "asfdf",
             "last_modified": "2016-11-11T16:42:52.240940"
         },
         "sp_rating": "AA-",
         "naic": "79413",
         "type": "STOCK",
         "name": "Spacewomen Insurance"
     },
     "has_pdf_app": true,
     "rate": {
         "quarter": 23841,
         "annual": 92964,
         "semi_annual": 47682,
         "month": 7747
     },
     "rating_class": "Standard",
     "fees": [{
           "name": "corgi discount",
           "type": "buddy"
     }]}
```

[Here is a live example of my issue](https://bl.ocks.org/TS000/620b0651cf280b128fb6dbf43aa5b490).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is *not* the "child of a child" that you are having trouble accessing, but a sibling property that is of the array type.

There are two problems with your example. First, `fees` is on the same level as `company_base`. When you are within the `{{#company_base}} {{/company_base}}` tags you are within the context of the `company_base` object, so must step-up *one* level in order to access its siblings. The correct path would be: `{{../fees}}`.

Your second issue is that `fees` is an array. You might want to `{{#each}}` over this array, but if you want only the first object, then you can access it like: `{{fees.0.type}}`.

This means that your template should be updated with the following:

```
<li><b>Type</b>: {{../fees.0.type}}</li>
<li><b>Name</b>: {{../fees.0.name}}</li>
```

That should do the trick. However, I would like to recommend an alternative way of writing your template. I would eliminate the need to step-up a level to get the `fees` object by removing the `{{#company_base}} {{/company_base}}` tags. This will mean that you are at the level of the current object in the `options` array and you can use dot notation to access its descendant properties. The updated template would look like the following:

```
{{#each options}}
    <div>
        <h1>{{company_base.name_full}}</h1>
        <b>AM Best Rating</b>: {{company_base.ambest_rating}}
        <p><b>Type</b>: {{company_base.business_type}}</p>
        <p>
            <b>Fees</b>:
            <ol>
                <li><b>Type</b>: {{fees.0.type}}</li>
                <li><b>Name</b>: {{fees.0.name}}</li>
            </ol>
        </p>
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

Note: I am opting for the more explicit `{{#each options}}` over `{{#options}}`.

I have created an example fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/pLorzd78/).

Comment: Thank you very much. Solved!